# LLDB exception after updating to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb, android-studio-3.1

After updating to Android Studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1, and updating all plugins and SDK tools i am no longer able to debug my native application.

The error is 'Execution finished' (ExecutionFinishedException) which is raised in LLDB.

LLDB version is 3.1.4508709 (which is the latest).

If i try and debug with an earlier version of LLDB i get an error LLDB is missing (or similar).

Error details:

```
Execution finished
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Execution finished
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.ExecutionResult.get(ExecutionResult.java:38)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.getProtobufClient(LLDBDriver.java:90)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.executeConsoleCommand(LLDBDriver.java:1109)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.executeConsoleCommand(LLDBDriver.java:1103)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadStartupScripts(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:321)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.commonLoad(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:132)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForAttach(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:248)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.prepareTarget(AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.java:101)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeDebugProcessImpl.doLoadTarget(AndroidNativeDebugProcessImpl.java:123)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess.lambda$start$0(CidrDebugProcess.java:314)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:703)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:693)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$0(QueueProcessor.java:93)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$wrappingProcessor$1(QueueProcessor.java:93)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$3(QueueProcessor.java:226)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$startProcessing$4(QueueProcessor.java:226)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionFinishedException: Execution finished
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver$4.processTerminated(LLDBDriver.java:248)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$5.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:239)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$4.run(ProcessHandler.java:196)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:272)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:177)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:173)
at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:192)
at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(OSProcessHandler.java:89)
at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:155)
at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:140)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor$1.run(ProcessWaitFor.java:66)
... 5 more
```

Last 2 lines from gdb-server log:

```
1522263876.330623627 NativeProcessLinux.cpp:MonitorCallback                       got exit signal(0x002EA90B) , tid = 25279 (is not main thread)
1522263876.330640793 NativeProcessLinux.cpp:MonitorCallback                       tid = 25279 handling non-main thread exit (%s)
```

Anyone else experienced this or know of a fix?

Comment: update your LLDB in sdk tools

Comment: thanks. LLDB is the latest version already though. When i go back to Android Studio 3.0.1 with the same version of LLDB i no longer get the issue. It only happens in AS 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to re-install Android Studio 3.0.1. This can be done alongside the latest version (see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html).

For me, debugging c++ code then works again (in Android Studio 3.0.1) even though it is using the same versions of SDK tools (e.g. LLDB v3.1.4508709).